# reading table using reader ASP.NET and VB

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a view patients page and it shows all patients and there's a link next to each patient which takes you to another page where the user can update the patient's information using textboxes and dropdownlists .. i used query string choose a certain patient and reader  command to read from the database ..
The problem is the reader isn't accessing the table at all .. can you help me please?

```
pid = Request.QueryString("Pateint_ID")

Dim tempQuery As String = "SELECT     P.first_name, P.sec_name, P.third_name, P.last_name, P.Gender, PATA.ApplicationStatus," & _
        "P.DoB, P.birthplace, P.Nationality, P.patient_ID, P.issue_date, P.issue_place, P.city, " & _
        "P.Area,h.Name , h.DialysisCetner, p.Mobile_No, p.Work_phone, p.PhoneNo, p.Zipcode, p.POBox, p.problemWithDialysis" & _
        "FROM         Association AS A INNER JOIN PatientApplyToAssociation AS PATA INNER JOIN" & _
        "patient AS P ON PATA.patient_ID = P.patient_ID ON A.Association_ID = PATA.Association_ID INNER JOIN " & _
        "hospital AS H INNER JOIN TreatmentSession AS ts ON  ts.Name = H.Name ON p.patient_ID = ts.patient_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN Family AS F INNER JOIN" & _
        "Gardian AS G ON F.family_ID = G.GID INNER JOIN Relates AS R ON F.family_ID = R.family_ID ON P.patient_ID = R.patient_ID" & _
        "WHERE     (P.patient_ID = pid )"

    Dim query As String = String.Format(tempQuery, pid)

    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(query, con)

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    Try

        con.Open()

        reader = comm.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read() Then
            txtFirstName.Text = reader("first_name").ToString()
            txtFatherName.Text = reader("sec_name").ToString()
            txtGrandName.Text = reader("third_name").ToString()
            txtFamilyName.Text = reader("last_name").ToString()
            rblGender.SelectedValue = reader("Gender").ToString()
            txtBirthdate.Text = reader("DoB").ToString()
            ddlBirthPlace.SelectedValue = reader("birthplace").ToString()
            txtNationality.Text = reader("Nationality").ToString()
            txtIDCard.Text = reader("patient_ID").ToString()
            ddlIssuePlace.SelectedValue = reader("issue_place").ToString()
            txtIssuedate.Text = reader("issue_date").ToString()
            ddlAddressCity.SelectedValue = reader("city").ToString()
            ddlAddressRegion.SelectedValue = reader("area").ToString()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("somthing's wrong")

    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: You've spelled PatientID correctly in the QueryString?

Comment: i fixed it but still not working it goes straight to the msgbox .. thanks

Comment: Does your code enter the `If reader.Read() Then` statement and error out?  Or does an exception get thrown.  You're `MsgBox("somthing's wrong")` should include the ex.Message at least: `MsgBox("somthing's wrong" & ex.Message)`

Comment: yes the exception gets thrown .. thanks

Comment: could be loads of things that ex.message should rovide a clue. debugging it would be useful as well.

Comment: yeah i added ex.message but i didn't understand what it says "Incorrect syntax near the key word 'AS'"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, im guessing its an SQL problem.  I would first take your query and run it in query analyzer to make sure its valid.

Your query looks incorrect.
After cleaning up your query so it was legible I noticed this

```
SELECT     P.first_name, P.sec_name, P.third_name, P.last_name, P.Gender, PATA.ApplicationStatus,
    P.DoB, P.birthplace, P.Nationality, P.patient_ID, P.issue_date, P.issue_place, P.city, 
    P.Area,h.Name , h.DialysisCetner, p.Mobile_No, p.Work_phone, p.PhoneNo, p.Zipcode, p.POBox, p.problemWithDialysis
    FROM         Association AS A INNER JOIN PatientApplyToAssociation AS PATA 
    INNER JOIN patient AS P ON PATA.patient_ID = P.patient_ID ON A.Association_ID = PATA.Association_ID 
    INNER JOIN hospital AS H 
    INNER JOIN TreatmentSession AS ts ON  ts.Name = H.Name ON p.patient_ID = ts.patient_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Family AS F 
    INNER JOIN Gardian AS G ON F.family_ID = G.GID INNER JOIN Relates AS R ON F.family_ID = R.family_ID ON P.patient_ID = R.patient_ID
    WHERE     (P.patient_ID = pid )
```

Notice 2 of your joins dont have `ON` clauses?  Not to mention you have 3 joins that have multiple `ON` clauses?